# Use ArcPy for finding value throughout all fields and export to new layer

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, cursor, loop, search

I need to find a way to find a specific value in the attribute table and then export all rows with said value to a new feature class.

Below is the code that I have managed to come up with (using other answers on this site). It gives the FID of the rows with the value searched but I can't find a way to select and export those records to a new file.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set the environment
workspace = r"\\C:\\GIS\\"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
fc = "species.shp"

# Get fields in the attribute table
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc, field_type='String')]
print(field_names)

# Loop through fields
for field in field_names:
    # Create a search cursor through rows in the feature class that looks for "In Danger" values and prints the record's FID number
    search = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "*")
    for row in search:
        if "In Danger" in row:
            print("In Danger value for FID {0}".format(row[0]))
            arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, 'new_fc', '{} like \'%{}%\''.format(field, 'In Danger'))
```

Comment: No need for a cursor - look into the Select (Analysis) tool.

Comment: Be cautious of using both raw formatting and double-backslashes on paths -- using one or the other will cause fewer complications.

Comment: I just simplified the path for this example; I had some complications when I started. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with PolyGeo, field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc, field_type = 'String')] then for field in field_names: arcpy.Select_analysis(fc,'Your Output','{} like \'*Danger*\''.format(field)) will find and export any features that have Danger in the field value - but beware some feature class storage types are case sensitive and some use * as a wildcard other use % as a wild card.

Comment: when I include the _f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields_, for some reason it prints all the values 8 times (once for every field in my table, I assume). But even then, _arcpy.Select_analysis_ generates an empty shapefile.

Comment: Do you really need to list your fields?  Won’t your “In Danger” values be in a single field?

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes please. The reason for [f.name for f in arcpy...] is that ListFields returns a list of *field* objects from which you're only wanting the field name. As to why you're getting an empty feature class I'd say it's because of the *, shapefiles use % as their wildcard so the expression becomes '{} like \'%Danger%\''.format(field)

Comment: @PolyGeo no, that's the problem. All the examples I find are easy because they query just one field. In this case, I have to query all and that's where I get stuck

Comment: If you have to look for the value in multiple fields then I would add a new field, use an update cursor to check for the value and update the new field if any field contains the value, leave the cursor and run Select_analysis to select on the value you used as your flag.

Comment: Don't use Select_analysis() within your cursor.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, I have updated the code. I'm closer now. Replacing the * by % generates a shapefile with 10 out of the 20 "In Danger" records. It apparently searches in the last filed only and ignores the others.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo I'll try that, too.

Comment: It's not that it only checks the *last field name* it's that it's overwriting the results of the previous field selections by using an arbitrary output name, try something like arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, 'new_fc_{}'.format(field),.. to output with different names. I also agree with PolyGeo, get rid of the search cursor altogether, it's not needed, all it will do is iterate with overwrite for each row slowing your execution for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I usually list OIDs of the rows meeting some condition then select using these:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\GIS\species.shp'

field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.type=='String']

oids_to_select = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['OID@']+field_names) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if 'In Danger' in row: #If in any of the listed field, append OID to list
        #If 'In Danger' can be a substring, for example 'ABC In Danger CDE' then try: if any(['In Danger' in substring for substring in row])
            oids_to_select.append(row[0])

sql = "{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc,arcpy.Describe(fc).OIDFieldName),tuple(oids_to_select))
arcpy.Select_analysis(fc,r'C:\GIS\species_selection.shp',sql)
```

Comment: This code does exactly what I need. I have some many things to learn from here though. For instance, I still don't understand what is that _f.name for f in_ in the 3rd line. I thought that _arcpy.ListFieldds(fc)_ was enough for that.

Comment: Nice. ListFields is listing [field objects](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm), not field names. But field object have properties like name and type which you can fetch using .name or .type. Input to the cursor need to be a list of field names so that line is listing the names using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip selection by using insert cursor, e.g.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
infc=r'...gdb\node_s'
outfc=r'....gdb\node_extract'
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(infc, outfc)
arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(outfc)
curT=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc,"*")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc,"*") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if "In Danger" not in row:continue
        curT.insertRow(row)
```